# Ubuntu 20.04: installing QGIS I get an error when it install python3-qgis

Tags: system-installation, gnupg, qgis

I am trying to re-intall qGIS in my ubuntu 20.04 following the [QGIS-installers](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu). However, I get an error when I try to install  the:

```
'sudo apt install gnupg software-properties-common'
```

The error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 34, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger'
dpkg: error processing package python3-qgis (--configure):
 installed python3-qgis package post-installation script subprocess returned err
or exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-qgis
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have read somethings about it, but I cannot understand yet what is happening. Can someone give me some advice?

Just to add more information in usr/lib/ I have 3 python folders: python2.7, python3, and python3.8. The second one 'python3' is empty. Maybe someone more clever than I can help me with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Felipe, have tried sudo apt install gnupg software-properties-common (without the ') ?

Comment: yes of course it does not work.

Comment: The strange thing is that an error is encountered on a pyhton3-qgis-package, which is not a program in gnupg neither in software-properties-common. The fact that the python3 is empty is abnormal. It should contain a lot of files. I assume that sudo apt update gives no errors? Then enter synaptic, try to repair packages or mark lib-python3-stdlib for complete installation

Comment: Thanks, @BernardDecock for your reply. What code line do you use to repair the lib-python3-stdlib?

Comment: You don't have to use code-lines. Start synaptic-package-manager. Search for python. Mark for complete installation. Then perform the action. Or follow the instructions described here https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-ubuntu

Comment: @BernardDecock he may have a Python not from official repository or different set up for paths

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu @felipeandreslobosroco , Would you edit the question and add output of these commands: `type -a python{,2,3}` , `which python{,2,3}` , `ls -l $(which python{,2,3})` , `echo $PATH` , `python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"` , `python3 -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"`